# sendFile in Discord.js does not send entire file

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a discord bot to share some files using the code below and do not understand something. When using the `sendFile` command, if I do not have a `new Buffer` parameter the bot closes without an error when it's called but with it the file is sent but has a size = to the buffer and is unusable.

```
"files": {
        description: "Replies with required files for setup",
        process: function(bot, msg, suffix){
        bot.sendFile(msg.channel, new Buffer("Not sure what this is"), "My\file\path")
         }
    }
```

Comment: add Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You can send *either* a Buffer a Path or an URL
`bot.sendFile(msg.channel, "My/file/path/image.jpg);`
will work just fine.